# Change boolean value for user object

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to be able to change my "sendmail" boolean value for a user via my view. But after adding the object once for a user with the value True I can't change it anymore because I get an "IntegrityError at /accounts/send_me_email/ column user_id is not unique". What am I doing wrong?

```
models.py

class SendMeMail(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    sendmail = models.BooleanField()
```

```
views.py

from userprofile.models import SendMeMail
def send_me_email(request):
    """
    Define if a user want email notifications or not
    """

    # Check for current sendmail value and act accordingly
    sendme = SendMeMail(user=request.user)

    if sendme.sendmail == False:
        sendme.sendmail = True
        sendme.save()
    if sendme.sendmail == True:
        sendme.sendmail = False
        sendme.save()
    else:
        sendme.sendmail = True
        sendme.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
sendme = SendMeMail(user=request.user)
```

doesn't do what you claim it does. It doesn't load the SendMeMail object with the current user from the database - it creates a *new* object for that user. Since you've (correctly) declared the user field as unique, this fails on save.

Instead, you mean this:

```
sendme = SendMeMail.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

Comment: Ofcourse! There is still some problem in my code since it hangs on False once it gets there but I suspect it is because I have two if:s after each other and the latter always changes it to False then.

Comment: Yes, just change the second if to `elif`.

Answer (score 0):

and maybe change

```
if sendme.sendmail == False:
    sendme.sendmail = True
    sendme.save()
if sendme.sendmail == True:
    sendme.sendmail = False
    sendme.save()
else:
    sendme.sendmail = True
    sendme.save()
```

to

```
sendme.sendmail = !sendme.sendmail
sendme.save()
```

it's shorter i think)